# Hundreds of Application Insights Snapshot Debugging Log Files - we didn't knowingly turn these on

Tags: azure, visual-studio-debugging, azure-application-insights

We have an Azure AppService, hosting a classic ASP.NET application.  We're noticing that the `D:\home\LogFiles` folder on the AppService has many hundreds of log files named `SnapshotUploader64_ABCDEF.log` where `ABCDEF` is 6 alphanumeric characters.  Many of these files are close to 100KB.

What are these files?  Why are there so very many, potentially filling up our Log space.

Each log file seems to be a trace of AppInsights PDP inspection, mini-dump writing and snapshot uploads.  Can this trace be turned off?

When we surf to the Kudu SCM DebugConsole page we see a long list of error messages in the Kudu console --

`There are xxx items in this directory, but maxViewItems is set to 299. You can increase maxViewItems by setting it to a larger value in localStorage.`

If they can't be turned off, can we have them put elsewhere, such as below the `LogFiles\ApplicationInsights` subfolder?

Comment: It sounds like you might have turned on AppInsights Snapshot Collector. Check your ApplicationInsights config file and see of the snapshot collector is turned on.

Comment: We did purposely turn Snapshot Collector on.  Is there a way to turn it’s logging off or move the log files into a separate folder?

Comment: according to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/snapshot-debugger#configure-snapshot-collection-for-aspnet-core-20-applications - I imagine you just need to set this node: <IsEnabled>false</IsEnabled>

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  `<IsEnabled>` appears to disable Snapshot Collection itself.  We  do want Snapshot Collection enabled, just want to have the logs go elsewhere, or not logging at all.

Comment: Yeah, and it seems like that isnt something you can do in the config file, which seems really weak actually.

Comment: @HowardHoffman Did you solved this somehow? I am looking for a solution that would delete old snapshot files, but I wasn't able to find one.

Comment: And a workaround is of course doing what the message suggest: opening the console in your browser (F12) and running `window.localStorage['maxViewItems'] = 1000` (where 1000 is your xxx items + some margin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a developer on Snapshot Collector. Currently users can't change the log path in Azure App Service or specify a lot rotation rule. I've added your feature request in our backlog and we'll probably implement it in the next release. Please follow the [release notes](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/issues/167).

As a workaround you can open Kudu in D:\home\LogFiles and run "rm SnapshotUploader*.log" to remove the old files. The current one will not be removed because it's locked by the running app.

If the app runs on any other platform them you can change the **TempFolder** configuration and logs will be written under **[TempFolder]\Dumps(64)\[instrumentation key]\**

Comment: Any updates on this? Cannot find it on release notes.

Comment: They are still happening as of `2020-01-05 21:11:58`.  Perhaps @ClaudiuGuiman can share whether this is expected or not.